# Passing GetMap requests to GeoServer from Flask

Tags: python, geoserver, leaflet, owslib, flask

For some reason, I try to use `Flask` as a proxy layer between client and server to control all requests sent to the `geoserver`.

The thing that I want to do is to send the `GetMap` request to the `GeoServer` through a `Flask` application to log some information and check some security matters and then allow the requests to reach  `GeoServer`. Finally I need to display the images as tiles to help map to be rendered faster and more optimized.

On the client side, I used Leaflet as follows:

```js
createWMSLayer(name: string): any {
    const wmsParams = new WMS(name);
    const url = `http://localhost:5000/geoservice/wms${createURLString(wmsParams)}`;
    var wmsLayer = new L.tileLayer.wms(url);
    wmsLayer.addTo(this.map);
}
```

On the server side, I used `flask` and `OWSlib` to check token and some other things:

```py
from owslib.wms import WebMapService

geoserver_rest_endpoint = f'http://{GEOSERVER_HOST}:{GEOSERVER_PORT}/geoserver/{ws}/wms'

wms = WebMapService(geoserver_rest_endpoint, version='1.1.1')

response = wms.getmap(
    layers=[layer_name, ],
    styles='',
    bbox=(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax),
    format='image/png',
    size=(256, 256),
    srs='EPSG:4326',
    time='2018-09-16',
    transparent=True)

return response.read()
```

The tiles are positioned successfully on map but the result is strange because the tiles are not being generated correctly. Here is the results.

What mistake am I making?

[image]

Comment: I think you are missing some steps from your question - are you making a tiled request to flask or trying to use it to take tiles from GeoServer and return a single large image to the client? Either way you need to add the code that calculates your bounding box and some example URLs

Comment: @IanTurton I added more information considering my issue. I want to display `GetMap` response on map in terms of tiles using `new L.tileLayer.wms(url)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking time, I could figure out the problem. It was due to setting wrong bounding box. I replaced it by one that comes from client.
On client side, I made these changes:

```js
const wmsParams = new WMS(name, true, 'image/png');
const url = `${environment.apiUrl}/geoservice/wms${createURLString(wmsParams)}`;
var wmsLayer = new L.tileLayer.wms(url);
```

in which, `WMS` is a class to create an object for WMS GetMap request:

```js
export class WMS {
    public name: string;

    constructor(name: string, transparent: boolean, format: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.transparent = transparent;
        this.format = format;
        this.token = getToken();
    }
}
```

In the `Flask` application, I removed `OWSLib` and re-wrote the code from the scratch as follow:

```py
args = request.args

if not decode_token(args.get('token')):
    return Response(
        json.dumps({"msg": "Unauthorized User!"}),
        status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN,
        mimetype='application/json')

layer_name = args.get('name', type=str).strip()

wms_params = {}
for _key, _val in request.args.items():
    if _key == 'token':
        continue
    if _key == 'transparent':
        _val = 'true'
    if _key in ['width', 'height']:
        _val = int(_val)
    if _key == 'layers':
        _val = f'{workspace_name}:{layer_name}'

    wms_params[_key] = _val

geoserver_rest_endpoint = f'http://{GEOSERVER_HOST}:{GEOSERVER_PORT}/geoserver/{workspace_name}/wms'

form_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(wms_params)
request_headers = {
    "Content-Length": str(len(form_data)),
    "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

r = requests.post(
    geoserver_rest_endpoint,
    data=urllib.parse.urlencode(wms_params),
    headers=request_headers,
    verify=False)

return Response(
    response=r._content,
    status=r.status_code)
```

Here is the results:
[image]